# Why do I keep getting "The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController" after sending data to controller? -Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im working with froms and db in Ruby on rails, these are all the documents in my model:

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_one :other
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
      @user = User.new
  end

  def create
      @user= User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
           redirect_to  @user
      else 
           redirect_to 'new'
      end
  end

 private
      def user_params   
       params.require(:user).permit(:nombre_usuario,:contrasena,:email)
      end
end
```

I can't make work the `redirect_to` line

users/new.html.rb:

```
<h1>Registro de Usuario</h1>
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>


<div class="field">
    <p>Nombre de Usuario</p>
    <% f.label :nombre_usuario %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :nombre_usuario%>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <p>e-mail</p>
    <% f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email%>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <p>Contraseña</p>
    <% f.label :contrasena %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :contrasena%>
</div>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ><%= f.submit 'Registrar' %></a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="/people/new.html"> 'Continuar'</a>
<br>
<% end %>
```

Everytime I click submit it sends me to another page that says "The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController"

I wish you could tell me another way to redirect, I tried a lot of ways and still can't make it work

Comment: `redirect_to  @user`... needs a `show` otherwise how would it show anything?

Comment: There is no show method in your users controller.

Comment: "I wish you could tell me another way to redirect" - where do you want to redirect to?

Answer (score 2):

add a show method in the controller

```
 def show;end
```

and make sure you have show.html.erb in the view/users folder.